# Python SUMを使ってフィルターを行う方法について

Tags: python, python3

Python3で `sum` を使ってExcelの行をフィルターして合計を求めたいです。
実現したい内容が上手くいかないので質問させて頂きます。
ご指導をお願いできますでしょうか。

**Excel Data**

| No | 国 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 |
| 1 | アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 |
| 2 | フランス | パリ | 13 |
| 3 | 日本 | 東京 | 26 |
| 3 | 日本 | 沖縄 | 14 |
| 3 | 日本 | 京都 | 11 |

実現したい内容の結果になります。
例：アメリカをフィルターしてsumで地域数の合計数を求めたいです。

**Excel Data Result**

| No | 国 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | 44 |

下記のコードでも試してみましたが、上手く希望通りの結果にならないです。
 `＆` 複数条件で行う必要ありますか。

```
import pandas as pd

#エクセルを読込み
filter= pd.read_excel('C:test.xlsx',sheet_name ='new_sheet_name')

#アメリカが含んでいデータをカウント
America=(filter == 'アメリカ').sum()
t=America.loc["アメリカ"]
print(t)

#地域数かつアメリカが含んでいデータをカウント
#America=(filter == 'アメリカ').sum()
regions=America.loc["地域数"]
print(regions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は [pandas.DataFrame.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas-dataframe-agg) を使う方法です。なお、Python3 には `filter` というクラスがデフォルトで存在するので、データフレーム名(`filter`)を別の名前(`df`)に置き換えています。

※ 動作確認のためデータフレームにデータを追加しています(`No` が 4 の行)。

| No | 国 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 |
| 1 | アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 |
| 4 | アメリカ | ニューヨーク | 42 |
| 4 | アメリカ | ロサンゼルス | 58 |
| 2 | フランス | パリ | 13 |
| 3 | 日本 | 東京 | 26 |
| 3 | 日本 | 沖縄 | 14 |
| 3 | 日本 | 京都 | 11 |

```py
dfx = (
  df[df['国']=='アメリカ']
    .groupby('No', as_index=False)
    .agg({'No':'first', '国':'first', '地域数':'sum'}))

print(dfx.to_markdown(index=False))
```

**出力結果**

| No | 国 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | 44 |
| 4 | アメリカ | 100 |

**追記**

> No、国、首都、地域数
>
> 1 アメリカ  ニューヨーク  カリフォルニア  地域数
> 2 アメリカ  空白  カリフォルニア  地域数
>
> のように首都に空白が入ると合計が上手く出力されないです。

> 上記のコードは同じ「国」であれば No は同じ、という前提で書きました。そうではないのですね？

> そうですね。

以下の様に書き直してみました。`No` についは最小値が表示されます。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
dfx = (
  df[df['国']=='アメリカ']
    .agg({'No':'min', '国':'min', '地域数':'sum'})
    .to_frame().T)
```

**Excel Data**

| No | 国 | 首都 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | ワシントン | ニューヨーク | 22 |
| 2 | アメリカ |  | カリフォルニア | 22 |
| 3 | フランス | パリ | パリ | 13 |
| 4 | 日本 | 東京 | 東京 | 26 |
| 4 | 日本 | 東京 | 沖縄 | 14 |
| 4 | 日本 | 東京 | 京都 | 11 |

**実行結果**

| No | 国 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | 44 |

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。都市のフロリダが空白の場合、合計が上手くされず0としてアカウントされます。空白を除外するステップが必要でしょうか。

Comment: また追加の質問ですが国の後に別の首都の列があるとするその列に空白があると上記のように合計が上手く出力されないです。こちらも同様に空白を除外するステップが必要でしょうか。

Comment: 手元で確認するとフロリダの地域数が空白の場合、合計は `22` と表示されるのですが、どの様な結果が望ましいのでしょうか？

Comment: 返事ありがとうございます。アメリカ の地域数を全てカウントして44であれば、`amarica.loc["地域数"]`で44だけの数字を取得したいです。ただ国の後に別の首都の列があるとするとその列に空白があると上記のように合計が上手く出力されないです。こちらも同様に空白を除外するステップが必要でしょうか。

Comment: 「都市」の列を増やしている、ということですか？ どちらにせよ、上記のコードでは`No` と `国` と `地域数` の列しか参照していません。

Comment: いえいえ、こちらのようになります。No、国、首都、地域数

Comment: No、国、首都、地域数　`1 アメリカ　ニューヨーク　カリフォルニア　地域数`　`2アメリカ　空白　カリフォルニア　地域数`のように首都に空白が入ると合計が上手く出力されないです。空白削除すると上手く出来ます。ただ削除せずにより良い方法ないか。調べて質問しました。

Comment: 上記のコードは同じ `国` であれば `No` は同じ、という前提で書きました。そうではないのですね？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね、なぜか前の列に空白が入ると上手く合計できないようです。フィルターは出来ます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記で上手く出来ました。度々、すいませんが44だけの数字を取得したいですがこちらのようにコード記載しましたが上手く44だけの数字が出力できます。`s=dfx['地域数']print(s.agg(['sum']))`

Comment: その場合は簡略的に書くことができます。`df[df['国']=='アメリカ']['地域数'].sum()`

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。上手くできました。

Answer (score 1):

[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)で`No`と`国`ごとにグループ化します。
グループ化した後に`sum`関数を呼び出すことでグループごとすなわち国ごとの地域数を合計します。
[query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query#pandas.DataFrame.query)で`国`が`アメリカ`の行を抽出します。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,"アメリカ","カリフォルニア",22],
                             [1,"アメリカ","フロリダ",22],
                             [2,"フランス","パリ",13],
                             [3,"日本","東京",26],
                             [3,"日本","沖縄",14],
                             [3,"日本","京都",11],
                            ],
                      columns = ["No", "国", "都市", "地域数"])

america = df.groupby(["No", "国"], as_index=False).sum().query("国 == 'アメリカ'")
print(america)
""" 
   No     国  地域数
0   1  アメリカ   44
"""
```

参考資料：

- [pandas.DataFrameの行を条件で抽出するquery](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-query/)
- [Pandas の groupby の使い方](https://qiita.com/propella/items/a9a32b878c77222630ae)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらも参考いたしますが、毎回データ不定的になりますので上記だと上手くいかないです。